# Cannot find libz.so.1 and other two libs when I've pass the path to the cmake

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux, opencv3.0

I sucessed to cross-compiled the opencv2.4.9 with another arm platform.This time I want to use the opencv3 ,because I need the contrib modules.But I've tried to cross-compiling the Opencv for a week,zlib png jpeg xvid ffmpeg those were been cross-compiled to a folder named opencv-depend.
when I use cmake to configure Opencv,I edit the ZLIB PNG JPEG path and filepath, the cmake-gui report that have found those libs

```
ZLib:                        /home/alinx/opencv-depend/lib/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
JPEG:                        /home/alinx/opencv-depend/lib/libjpeg.so (ver 90)
WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
PNG:                         /home/alinx/opencv-depend/lib/libpng.so (ver 1.6.18)
```

but when I generate the makefile,start to make,the terminal returned this

```
    [ 41%] Built target opencv_ts
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_core
/opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.4/gnu/arm/lin/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/../../../../arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: libz.so.1, needed by ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3.1, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.4/gnu/arm/lin/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/../../../../arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: libjpeg.so.9, needed by ../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.4/gnu/arm/lin/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/../../../../arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: libpng16.so.16, needed by ../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_filter@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_get_IHDR@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_write_image@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `gzeof'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_compression_strategy@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_gray_to_rgb@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_error@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_interlace_handling@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_write_info@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_palette_to_rgb@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_read_update_info@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_resync_to_restart@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_bgr@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `gzrewind'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_quality_scaling@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_rgb_to_gray@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_calc_output_dimensions@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_quality@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_tRNS_to_alpha@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `gzopen'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_compress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_16@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_simple_progression@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_write_fn@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `gzclose'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `gzgets'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_write_end@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_packing@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_read_info@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_read_image@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_default_qtables@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_read_end@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src@LIBJPEG_9.0'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `gzputs'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_read_fn@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_get_tRNS@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_compression_level@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_swap@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_init_io@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_alpha@PNG16_0'
../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3.1: undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table@LIBJPEG_9.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_perf_core] error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] error 2
make: *** [all] error 2
```

I searched for some helps,but they are not with cross-compiling problem,I think I've assigned the lib Path,why these cannot be recognized?here I give the complete CmakeCache file.

```
    General configuration for OpenCV 3.3.1-dev =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /home/lzx/Documents/opencv_contrib-master/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2017-11-23T13:23:11Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.4.0-98-generic x86_64
    Target:                      Linux arm
    CMake:                       2.8.12.2
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    NEON FP16
      requested:                 DETECT
      disabled:                  VFPV3 NEON

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.4/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-g++  (ver 4.9.2)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.4/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      
    Linker flags (Debug):        
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml objdetect photo video dnn imgcodecs shape videoio highgui superres ts features2d calib3d stitching videostab aruco
    Disabled:                    js world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 python3 viz

  GUI: 
    QT:                          NO
    GTK+:                        NO
    GThread :                    NO
    GtkGlExt:                    NO
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /home/alinx/opencv-depend/lib/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        /home/alinx/opencv-depend/lib/libjpeg.so (ver 90)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         /home/alinx/opencv-depend/lib/libpng.so (ver 1.6.18)
    TIFF:                        NO
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     NO
    GDAL:                        NO
    GDCM:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      NO
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    Aravis SDK:                  NO
    UniCap:                      NO
    UniCap ucil:                 NO
    V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Xine:                        NO
    Intel Media SDK:             NO
    gPhoto2:                     NO

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES ()

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use Intel IPP:               NO
    Use Intel IPP IW:            NO
    Use VA:                      NO
    Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
    Use Lapack:                  NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  NO
    Use OpenVX:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4.3)

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              NO

  Install path:                  /home/lzx/Documents/opencv-install

  cvconfig.h is in:              /home/lzx/Documents/opencv-master/build
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
Generating done
```

and those libs are what I've cross-compiled with the arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi toolchains

```
:/home/alinx/opencv-depend/lib# ls
libavcodec.a              libavutil.so            libpostproc.so
libavcodec.so             libavutil.so.54         libpostproc.so.53
libavcodec.so.56          libavutil.so.54.31.100  libpostproc.so.53.3.100
libavcodec.so.56.60.100   libjpeg.a               libswresample.a
libavdevice.a             libjpeg.la              libswresample.so
libavdevice.so            libjpeg.so              libswresample.so.1
libavdevice.so.56         libjpeg.so.9            libswresample.so.1.2.101
libavdevice.so.56.4.100   libjpeg.so.9.0.0        libx264.so
libavfilter.a             libpng16.a              libx264.so.148
libavfilter.so            libpng16.la             libyasm.a
libavfilter.so.5          libpng16.so             libz.a
libavfilter.so.5.40.101   libpng16.so.16          libz.so
libavformat.a             libpng16.so.16.18.0     libz.so.1
libavformat.so            libpng.a                libz.so.1.2.8
libavformat.so.56         libpng.la               pkgconfig
libavformat.so.56.40.101  libpng.so
libavutil.a               libpostproc.a
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any linker flags telling the compiler where to find the necessary libraries to link against

```
Linker flags (Release):      
Linker flags (Debug):
```

Adding the necessary paths would help in solving this for you. e.g. add

```
-L/home/alinx/opencv-depend/lib
```